# How plausible is my continent-wide rainforest?

Tags: science-based, climate, geography

I’m trying to refine the worldbuilding for the planet featured in my story “Aleyara’s Descent” from the May/June 2023 *Analog Science Fiction and Fact*. The planet is 86% the diameter of Earth with 82% gravity, and has a Jurassic-like climate, warm and wet with maybe 25% oxygen or more, supporting a lush biosphere with abundant megafauna. It rotates a little slower than Earth, in 27 hours, 23 minutes, and has a moon 84% the size of Luna but a bit further out.

The most notable feature is the rainforest, consisting of gigantic trees more than 150 meters high with a canopy so densely grown together that it’s almost like solid ground. The trees share water and nutrients through their branches, becoming a single superorganism; they also secrete a fire-resistant resin to counter the high-oxygen atmosphere. This much is already established in the published story, so it should be treated as a given.

My intent is that the rainforest covers nearly 60% of the land surface, because most of the land is in the tropics or subtropics, and the planet’s 9.6-degree axial tilt and current geology result in year-round steady rainfall for a broad region around the equator. A lower axial tilt would technically mean a narrower tropical zone, but I’m assuming it would result in less seasonal variation in the weather. High mountains to the north trap moisture on their southern side and enhance the wetness of the rainforest.

I created a rough map some years back by editing random fractal planetscapes generated by the Terranova screensaver (so this isn’t a flat projection, just two hemisphere views). It’s not entirely accurate, and the ratio of water to land should probably be greater.

[image: Approximate map of planet Rulenau]

Roughly, the dark green is the super-rainforest, the lighter green is more conventional forest, etc. The big northern mountain range starts at the northeastern peninsula of the supercontinent and extends west-southwest; I assume the yellow-green spur extending southwest from the northern coast is a steppe or desert in the rain shadow of the mountains. The planet’s too warm for permanent icecaps, but the northernmost lands consist of tundra, desert, and glaciated mountains, so they’re inhospitable.

The main problem here, as I understand it, is that the middle of that single vast supercontinent should be very dry, because it’s far from the oceans. So the question is, how do I get enough moisture there to sustain the rainforest? It is narrowest there, but is it plausible for it to be there at all? There are several factors that could help. There’s the northern mountain range trapping moisture to the south. There’s the interconnected superorganism of the trees sharing moisture and nutrients throughout, and the transpiration of moisture from their leaves would itself increase the humidity. Since the forest is mostly in the intertropical convergence zone, I presume there’s no fixed wind direction, so winds from the southern inland seas might blow north and east to help supply moisture, at least in monsoon seasons.

Does this work well enough as is, or do I need to make some changes to the geography? Are there problems I’m missing? Are there solutions I’m missing? Would the lower gravity or slower rotation have an effect, for better or worse?

EDIT:

All right, here's a rough attempt at an improved map:

[image: Rulenau version 2]

I didn't want to get entirely rid of the land in the far north -- is this good enough to get a reasonable amount of moisture continent-wide?

Also, about how much of an axial tilt would be preferable? Since Hadley cells help distribute moisture and heat, should I go for a larger tilt than Earth's for larger cells? Will I have to accept more severe seasons as a tradeoff?

Answer (score 3):

It's not, you have created a mostly desert continent.

You have done nearly everything possible to ensure as much desert as you can.

Low axial tilt means smaller Hadley cells, which means mess moisture in the tropical zone and a smaller tropical zone. Most of the continent is in the subtropical highs, it will be mostly desert just due to that.

You have too much land, somewhere between 2-3 times as much as Earth, and not enough ocean so your planet is a lot drier than Earth. There are no monsoons on this planet. There might not even be hurricanes.

The huge continent makes it even drier so a lot of your tropics will also be dry because they don't have anywhere from which to get moisture.

These are such dominant forces that there is not much you can do about them. You have to change them. Slowing the rotation a lot will help but only if you have a lot more ocean. That way you have a single set of large circulation cells instead of 3. This does mean your moisture would be coming from the north and south more than the east.

Comment: Okay, so smaller continent and larger axial tilt -- easy enough to fix. I already said the map was only an approximation that probably exaggerated the land/water ratio, so don't take its proportions literally. I'm more concerned with the geography of the continent. Assuming a proportionally smaller continent of the same shape to start with, what else do I need?

Comment: get rid of the northwestern peninsula so moisture can come in from every side.  that should take care of most of it.

Comment: On the question of where to get moisture... what about groundwater? What if the central portion of the continent were low enough that it breached the water table and turned into wetlands? Online maps suggest that a subsurface aquifer can span a major part of a continent, though the locations don't necessarily correspond to wet areas, due to their depth: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Simplified-version-of-a-global-groundwater-resources-map9-highlighting-the-locations-of_fig1_258807224

Comment: @ChristopherBennett groundwater needs to come from somewhere if plants have access to it it will disappear quickly unless it it replaced just as quickly. the height of the water table is controlled by rainfall, death valley is lower than sea level. You may need to create a new question just about Hadley cells,

Comment: I know, which is why I brought up the issue of how large an aquifer can be. If it spans a wide enough part of the continent, it might bring water from a rainier area into a drier area. The largest aquifers on the map I linked to are thousands of kilometers wide. And since my planet has a hot, wet climate like the Eocene, with no ice caps to take water out of circulation, it could have a considerably greater surplus of water than present-day Earth and thus have larger or deeper underground aquifers.

Comment: the issue is to bring it long distance you need highlands, which means rain shadow. also depth is the issue to be accessed by plants an aquifer needs to be shallow. you would be better off with a central highlands and rivers bringing water further out. you still need to find out how to make the Hadley cell as big as possible.

Comment: Well, there is supposed to be a mountain range running from the northeast peninsula down along the southeastern side of that yellow-green spur. I imagine that rivers run down from there toward the south or southeast and hydrate much of the eastern half of the continent, much like the Amazon basin.

Comment: @jdunlop According to this, Hadley cell size has nothing to do with axial tilt: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/19862/how-are-climate-regions-caused-by-both-axial-tilt-and-also-by-climate-circulatio

Tilt only affects how much the seasons vary, as I thought. Larger Hadley cells result from slower rotation and higher temperature, and my planet has both. It seems the most important thing is to have most of the land in the intertropical convergence zone where rainfall is most constant.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett - I think you meant to tag someone else?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett that's an indirect question try asking what controls Hadley cells directly, tilt a which controls how evenly the planet is heated, and rotational speed has an effect, as does thickness of atmosphere. there is an existing question but it does not go into the effects of atmosphere thickness or tilt. https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/992/what-factors-determine-the-number-of-hadley-cells-for-a-planet

Comment: @ChristopherBennett this should be helpful https://www.cps-jp.org/~mosir/pub/2016/2016-11-29/01_showman/lecture03/pub-web/20161129_showman_lec03.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but both of your links are things I already found in my research earlier this evening.

Comment: Dry means no resin, means a eternal fire column like blaze walking along the forrest belt..

Answer (score 1):

Rainforest can generate, at least at some scales, their own weather.   See "A rainforest-initiated wet season onset over the southern Amazon" in PNAS.  While this may not be able to solve everything, it's a realistic mechanism by which the forest recycles moisture.  As stated by "Forest-rainfall cascades buffer against drought across the Amazon", "We estimate that one-third of Amazon rainfall originates within its own basin"   Whether this phenomena could occur on a super continent is probably another issue.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Between that and the wet, hothouse climate, it might work. I likened the climate to the Jurassic, but a thread about a similar question suggested an analogy with the Eocene, when most of North America and Eurasia were covered in forest.

Answer (score 1):

Make the center of the supercontinent a depression below sea level, with the edges of the elevated slightly to form a rain trap, and all the inland aquifers, rivers and streams going towards it.

Basically, imagine there is a giant sweetwater lake in the middle of the continent, but the plant growth had all but covered it, and siphoned the water to the sides, resulting in a sea-sized, rainforest covered swamp.

Comment: Great, that sounds like a more plausible way to get a midcontinent wetland. Although what gives me pause about the swamp idea is whether it would be a strong enough base to support my super-redwood rainforest trees. But the roots would have to be very wide and deep anyway to support all that weight, so a few meters of water on the ground might not make that much difference. It could be an interesting environment to use in a story.

Answer (score 0):

All right, here's a rough attempt at an improved map:
[image: Rulenau version 2]

I didn't want to get entirely rid of the land in the far north -- is this good enough to get a reasonable amount of moisture continent-wide?

Also, about how much of an axial tilt would be preferable? Since Hadley cells help distribute moisture and heat, should I go for a larger tilt than Earth's for larger cells? Will I have to accept more severe seasons as a tradeoff?

Comment: Just make this an edit not an answer.

Comment: Okay, I've done that. Thanks for letting me know.