# Can I have a supercontinent that is wet in its interior?

Tags: climate, prehistoric-times, weather

I recently learned that there was a period in Earth's history called the Carnian pluvial episode, when rainfall was extremely high for about 2 million years, and even the interior of large continents was relatively wet. One video said that many former deserts could receive as much as 1200 mm (46 in) of rain.

I want nearly all land on my planet (a supercontinent like Pangea) to be covered by forests of some form. I also want temperatures to be like modern Earth, with distinct temperate and arctic zones, but with Carnian-level rainfall. How do I mirror this effect on my planet?

(Note: It doesn't have to be permanent. In the scale of humans, being in the middle of a 2 million year period of high rain would mean it's all we'd ever known.)

Answer (score 3):

Please note that 1,200 mm of annual rain is twice the amount of rain received by the notoriously wet England. That's a lot of rain.

While opinions are still unsettled about exactly how wet the [Carnian Pluvial Event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnian_pluvial_episode) was, [one possibility](https://paleonerdish.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/the-triassic-paleoclimate/) is that massive volcanic eruptions released enormous amounts of carbon dioxide, reaching an astonishing 4,500 parts per million, leading to the temporary establishment of a hothouse climate, very warm and rainy. Or, of course, the usual paleoclimatic handwave: multiple asteroid impacts.

But you do not have to go all that way back to find a warm and rainy hothouse Earth; much closer to our times, 65 to 35 million years ago, the early and middle [Eocene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eocene) period was also hot and rainy, with forest growing at the poles and rainforests covering most of North America.

The one thing you cannot have when Earth's climate is in a hothouse period is ice; and no ice means really high sea levels: in the early and mid Eocene, sea levels were some 150 meters (500 feet) higher than at present.

Comment: I'm not buying the 150m figure here... last time I tried to calculate how high would seas rise if all Earth's ice would melt, I came up with ~80 meters. And Earth must not lose half of its water in those 60MY from Eocene to present.

Comment: @Vesper you can chase some references, though they tend to be paywalled. Wikipedia references [Paleocene–Eocene and Plio–Pleistocene sea-level changes as “species pumps” in Southeast Asia: Evidence from Althepus spiders](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1055790317306802?via%3Dihub) which in turn reference a handful of papers giving 150m rises, and some more suggesting 100m rises. I'm having problems with scihub at the moment, though you may have better sources than me.

Answer (score 2):

### Have a wet interior

The main source of wetness for a continent is water. The sea, the oceans, rivers all that. So, to have a wet super continent, have it be wet. Have countless rivers and massive lakes and seas on the inside of the super continent which have enormous volumes of water running through them.

That will ensure your land can be wetter without the substantial side effects of massive volcanic eruptions in the carnian pluvial episodes.

Comment: I asked a strikingly similar question the other day ( https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/256515/how-plausible-is-my-continent-wide-rainforest ), and I was told that the size of the supercontinent relative to the ocean was important, that you had to have enough ocean to provide sufficient water for monsoons, etc. So I'd say it's important not to make the continent *too* super.

Also, are rivers alone enough? The Nile is a major river, but it's just got a narrow strip of green around it in the middle of a desert.

Comment: That's why I said countless rivers. It would be unusual to have that much water flowing, but if you have enough rivers it would act similarly to having an equal amount of sea.

Comment: Is that realistic, though? Rivers have to come from somewhere. If the continent's interior is too far from the oceans for sufficient rainfall to replenish its moisture, then the lakes and rivers will eventually dry up. There are many rivers in arid regions that only flow for part of the year. Abundant rivers and lakes are an effect of abundant moisture in the climate, not a cause of it.

Comment: It running out eventually isn't an issue, see op's post.

Comment: I'm more concerned with the question of whether and how it could have come about in the first place. Those inland seas and rivers couldn't have formed if there hadn't been enough moisture reaching the middle of the supercontinent at *some* point in its history, so the question remains, how did the water get there originally? Hmm... Maybe the seas are what's left of the ocean between two continents that are colliding. Eventually the "seam" will push up into a mountain range, but right now it's still early in the collision and the seas are the remaining gaps between land masses.